# how to print (with printer ) a excel sheet with python with print area

Tags: python, excel, printing, openpyxl

I'm trying to launch prints on my printer from python but with a print_area.

I tried this code (code from chat GPT) but it doesn't work. The printer print the entire sheet and not the print-area i defined.

```
import win32com.client
import openpyxl


def imprimer_feuille_excel(nom_fichier, nom_feuille):
    # définition de la zone d'impression
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(nom_fichier)
    feuille = wb[nom_feuille]
    feuille.print_area = 'A1:J10'
    wb.save(nom_fichier)

    #impression
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False  # Pour rendre Excel invisible pendant le processus
    classeur = excel.Workbooks.Open(nom_fichier)
    feuille = classeur.Sheets[nom_feuille]
    feuille.PrintOut()  # Imprimer la feuille
    classeur.Close(SaveChanges=False)  # Fermer le classeur sans sauvegarder les modifications
    excel.Quit()
```

Even when print_area is defined manually in excel, this code print the entire page (if i could print with print_area defined in excel, it coud be enough for me)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do all the required with just win32com or Xlwings, no need to preset the print area with Openpyxl. That step may be the root of your issue.

Win32com

```
from win32com import client

xlfile = r'<path>\foo.xlsx'
sheet = 'Sheet1'


excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False  # Pour rendre Excel invisible pendant le processus
classeur = excel.Workbooks.Open(xlfile)
feuille = classeur.Sheets[sheet]

feuille.PageSetup.PrintArea = 'A1:J10'

feuille.PrintOut()  # Imprimer la feuille

classeur.Close(SaveChanges=False)  # Fermer le classeur sans sauvegarder les modifications
excel.Quit()
```

Xlwings alternative

```
import xlwings as xw

xlfile = 'foo.xlsx'
sheet = 'Sheet1'

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(xlfile)  # Open workbook
    ws = wb.sheets[sheet]  # Open Sheet

    ws.page_setup.print_area = 'A1:J10'  # Set print Area
 
    # Set page layouts if needed like fitting the print onto one page width 
    ws.api.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1  

    ws.api.PrintOut(Copies=1, IgnorePrintAreas=False)  # Print the page
```

That's all that should be necessary for either module other than other Page Settings if required.
For example if you wanted landscape orientation instead of portrait then in Xlwings you could use;

```
ws.api.PageSetup.Orientation = 2  # xlLandscape
```

and similar setting for win32com

xlLandscape is an Excel constant which you can read in from Xlwings Constants or just set the numeric value (the default xlPortrait = 1)

Comment: You're greater than chatgpt ( at least for a noob like me ! )